# Prime number program in haskell

Tags: haskell

I was looking up a program in Haskell that tests if a given number is prime or not.

```
prime :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
prime 1 = True
prime x = and [ x `mod` y /= 0 | y <- [2..(x-1)] ]
```

I don't understand what is the purpose of this `and` in: `prime x = and [`.

Comment: 1 is not a prime number though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this question has been answered, please allow me to add a few things:
When examining the source of `and`, you get:

```
and :: [Bool] -> Bool
and = foldr (&&) True
```

First thing to notice is that `and` takes a list of Boolean variables, and returns a single Boolean variable, and that the expression `x mod y /= 0` evaluates to True or False (Hence fitting the [Bool] requirement) .

More important to notice is that `foldr` is a lazy-fold. So a lazy fold here is optimal because `&&` is a semi-strict operator. Hence a lazy fold in combination with a semi-strict operator will yield a short-circuit evaluation upon encountering the first occurence of a `False`. Hence in the cases of actual *non-prime numbers*, `and` will avoid evaluating the entire list, consequently saving you time as a result. Don't take my word for it, define your own strict version of `and` if you want (using the stricter `foldl`):

```
andStrict :: [Bool] -> Bool
andStrict x = foldl (&&) True

primeStrict :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
primeStrict x = andStrict [x `mod` y /= 0 | y <- [2..(x-1)]]
```

Now run:

```
prime 2000000000
```

Notice how that was fast? Now do this, but interrupt it before it crashes your memory-stack:

```
primeStrict 2000000000
```

That was obviously slower, you were able to interrupt it. This is the role of `and`, and that is why `and` was written with `foldr`, and hence why it was chosen for the example code you posted. Hope that helps as a supportive answer.

Answer (score 2):

`and` performs a *logical and* operation on all elements of a list.

Primes are only divisible by one and themselves; this means that as soon as a divisor (without a remainder) exists between 2 inclusive and your `x` exclusive, the number is not a prime.

The list comprehension generates a list of Boolean values that correspond to whether your `x` is  or is not divisible by numbers from within the said range.

As soon as any of them is false (a division occurred with a zero remainder), the number is not a prime.

Consider:

```
x = 7
[7 % 2 /= 0 -> True, 7 % 3 /= -> True, ...]
-- now applying and
True && True && ... && True evaluates to True
```

`and` can be represented as a more general operation that can be performed on lists - a *fold* using *logical and*. Such as: `and' = foldr (&&) True`.

Comment: if it performs a logical and operation, shouldn't it be like this : `&&` ?

Comment: @unexim and takes 1 argument: a list of boolean values; (&&) takes 2 arguments: two boolean values

Comment: @unexim  Again, `and [a,b,c,d]` is the same as `a && b && c && d` hence `and` cannot be named `&&`.

Comment: more precisely, `and [a,b,c,d] == a && b && c && d && True`.

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
[x `mod` y /= 0 | y <- [2..(x - 1)]
```

is a list of `Bool`s because `mod x y /= 0` (prefix notation because of backtick formatting) returns a `Bool`.  The `and` function just does a logical AND of every element in a list, so

```
and [True, False] == False
and [True, True] == True
```